# change file name c# with a loop

Tags: c#, file, pdf, file-rename

I have to Change the Name of some pdfs(1,2 TB). The Name of the files is for example 20160112_0(year/month/day/_0). I have to Change the file Name to tu, 12.January 2016(weekday/day/month/year).

I allready got the filename but i dont know how to Change it right.

```
string dir = @"path";
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
        foreach (string file in files)
            Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(file));
```

Comment: "i dont know how to Change it right" can you elaborate?  What is the problem you're having>?

Comment: File.Move(oldName, newName)

Comment: Are you looking for [`File.Move`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: give a proper example of a name change, you cant use commas or dots for the file name..

Comment: You want to change the date format in the filename?

Comment: @Innat3 what stops you of using commas and dots for the file name? they are valid.

Comment: i allready tried this with file.move but it dosent solve my problem

Comment: @Gusman it is good practice to avoid those characters for cross platform reliability https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202808

Comment: it would be fine if i could split this file Name and save it into integers but i dont know how to split 20160112_0 into 3 ints day, month and year.

Comment: @Innat3 is not the same to be good practice for cross-platform and to be an invalid example. Also, even for apple platforms these are valid chars, they only mean that usually files or folders which start with dots are used for hidden configs and so on, that document seems more focused on regular user best practices than programming best practices as they already note "These characters are often reserved for special functions in scripting and programming languages"

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? you started with asking about renaming a file and now you're talking about saving file name "into integers".  Please elaborate.

Comment: i am have to rename pdf file like i said and i also said how they are named. I Need the day month and the year from the file which is in the Name.

Comment: @Gusman Sorry, I agree I didn't word that correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        string dir = @"YourPath";
        string fileDate, new_fileDate;
        DateTime dt;
        foreach (string original_filename in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
        {
            fileDate = Path.GetFileName(original_filename).Substring(0, 8);
            dt = DateTime.ParseExact(fileDate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            new_fileDate = dt.ToString("ddd_dd_MMMM_yyyy");
            File.Move(original_filename, original_filename.Replace(fileDate, new_fileDate));
        }
```

Comment: @LovedeepSingh just change new_fileDate = dt.ToString("") to whatever format suits you best, you can find the datetime related keywords here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you. You saved me a lot of time  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
//from your code: 
DateTime fileDate;
var newFileName = newFileName(Path.GetFileName(file), out fileDate);
File.Move(newFileName);


string newFileName(string oldFileName, out DateTime fileDate)
    {

        var fileDate =  DateTime.ParseExact(oldFileName.Take(8),
                                            "yyyyMMdd",
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                            DateTimeStyles.None) ;

    var nfn = fileDate.Day.ToString() + "." + fileDay.Month.ToString("MMM") + fileDay.Year.ToString("YYYY") + ".pdf";

    return nfn;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string path = @"path";
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = System.IO.DirectoryInfo(path);
    foreach System.IO.FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles()){
        string newname = GetNewName(file.Name);
if(newname!=file.Name)
        file.Move(file.FullName,  System.IO.Path.Combine(file.DiretoryName, newname);
    }

    public string GetNewName(string f){
       string without_ext = f.split('.').First();
    string result = f;
       Match m = Regex.Match(without_ext, "(\\d{4})(\\d[012]?)(\\d[0123]?\\d)")
        if(m.Success){
           result = $"{m.Groups[3].Value}.{CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(int.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value)} {m.Groups[1].Value).{f.split('.').Last()}}; 
       }
       return result;
    }
```